# I don't understand what to use to check all values in an array?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project10C {
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int [] finalarray = new int [5];
int [] test = new int [1000];
int x = 1000;
int temp1;

for ( int i = 0; i <= 4;i++){
    System.out.println ( "Input a number between 1 and 25 inclusive: " );
    temp1 = reader.nextInt();
    test[i] = temp1;
    if ( i > 0 ){
        if ( temp1 == test[i] ) {
        System.out.print ("Sorry that number has already been entered.");
                break;

        }
        else {
            finalarray[i]= temp1;
```

Did not include brackets in this question. Point of this code is check if numbers inputted have already been entered. I'm having difficulty trying checking if the number they input is equal to values in an already existing array. In this:

```
if (temp1 == test[i] ){
```

From my own knowledge this will only check the current array going through this if statement every time. Should I be using another for statement? If so what would I put for the second parameter of the for statement?

Comment: You'd want another loop that goes from 0 to i.

Comment: How will this help me?

Comment: Do you mean adding that if statement in a for loop that starts at 0 and goes to i?

Comment: @JackStudentMHS-Please visit my answer and kindly upvote and accept it if it wworks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The easiest way is probably using another loop inside the main loop, as follow:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 4;i++){
    System.out.println ( "Input a number between 1 and 25 inclusive: " );
    temp1 = reader.nextInt();

    boolean repeated = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(finalarray[j] == temp1) {
            // the number is already entered.
            repeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(repeated)
        break;

    // number is not entered before
    finalarray[i] = temp1;
}
```

Actually when you're reading i-th number, you have to check every number from 0 to (i - 1) in the array to not be equal with entered number.

However, if there are a lot of numbers, using a data structure like Set is preferable. Just add every number to the set and then you can easily check if a new number is previously entered:

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp1 = reader.nextInt();

    if(numbers.contains(temp1)) {
        // already entered
        break;
    }

    // number is not entered before
    // add it to our array
    finalarray[i] = temp1;

    // also put it in the set for future checks
    numbers.add(temp1);
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be j <= i?

Comment: No, it should be j < i. Because you're reading i-th number and you have to check from 0 to (i - 1).

Comment: Oh I see if i used <= then it would give me an error every time? Because the value of the array in that index would be what the number I entered?

Comment: It won't give you an error, but the program wouldn't work correctly, because i-th cell is not filled with a legit number yet. See it like this: you want to put a number in 4th cell, so you have to check previous cells, from 0 to 3, thus j < i.

Comment: I made a small edit to my answer. Now if user inputs a repeated number, it will exit the main loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need another for-loop to compare previous elements of final-array with the entered input as recommended in my solution. Also, the loop would iterate always from `0 to i`---the key thing!

The solution goes as :-

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 4;i++){
System.out.println ( "Input a number between 1 and 25 inclusive: " );
temp1 = reader.nextInt();
for( int j=0;j<i;j++){
if(temp1==finalarray[j]){
 System.out.println("Sorry that number has already been entered.");
 break;
}
else 
 finalarray[i]= temp1;

}
}
```

Comment: With this code segment, when I test it, I put in 1 first time, and 2 for 2nd time and it breaks giving me an ArrayOutofBoundsException for the if ( temp1 == finalarray[j] ) line. Any clue why?

Comment: @JackStudentMHS-SORRY,it woould be `j<i` as it'll be checking upto previos inputs which is from 0 to i-1. SORRY---please correct and modify it.

Comment: It shouldn't be j <= i, because the i-th cell is not filled with anything yet. Also the `break` is in wrong place! It only checks finalarray[0], and the exits from the inner loop.

Comment: @JackStudentMHS-Also,you can upvote answers from ticking the `up-vote counter` which is still 0.And,for acceptance---http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Sadjad-THANKS,corrected it! Earlier it was fine,I don't know why I did it!!! BTW,a +1 for you...

Comment: Cool Thanks for telling me that. Also thanks for the help a lot guys. I'll upvote both of your answers and accept the first one's since he was correct first :P.

Comment: @JackStudentMHS-Yeah,accept Sadjad's answer. he was correct!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a primitive array, or can you use an ArrayList? If you can use an ArrayList:

```
List<int> myArrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    System.out.println ( "Input a number between 1 and 25 inclusive: " );
    temp1 = reader.nextInt();

    /* The array list already has the input number. */
    if (myArrayList.contains(temp1)) {
        System.out.print ("Sorry that number has already been entered.");
        break;
    /* The array list does not contain the input number. */
    } else
        myArrayList.add(temp1);
}
```

Also, are you only trying to allow 4 digit numbers to be input?